# Un-suspend elements in hidden part in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

When I use standard Shiny, a change in the `tabPanel` somehow tells the output elements to un-suspend and show their value:

```r
library(shiny)

ui1 <- fluidPage(
   tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Start", p("Nothing to see here, really")),
      tabPanel("Calc", actionButton("do", "Calc"), verbatimTextOutput("out"))
   )
)

server1 <- function(input, output, session) {
   output$out <- renderPrint({
      input$do
   })
}
shinyApp(ui1, server1)
```

works as expected.

Now, if I switch to another framework ( `bulma` in this case), the elements stay suspended. In order to make them work I have to explicitly switch off the `suspendWhenHidden` flag.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinybulma)

ui2 <- bulmaPage(
   bulmaTabs(
      c("Start", "Calc"),
      center = FALSE,
      bulmaTab("Start", p("Nothing to see here, really")),
      bulmaTab("Calc", bulmaActionButton("do", "Calc"), verbatimTextOutput("out"))
   )
)

server2 <- function(input, output, session) {
   ## Need to comment out to make it run
   # session$onFlushed(function() {
   #    outputOptions(output, 
   #                  "out",
   #                  suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
   # })
   output$out <- renderPrint({
      input$do
   })
}

shinyApp(ui2, server2)
```

I assume that there is a (JS?) trigger attached to a change in `tabSets` which un-suspends the elements once the element is shown. How can I do the same for the `bulma` case? In other words, how can I un-suspend the elements once the respective part is shown (either JS/R is fine)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference: I issued a "bug" report on the [github repo of shiny](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3136). As assumed there is an event which needs to be triggered  (`shown`) in order to get that work (on tab change in this case)

I submitted a [PR](https://github.com/RinteRface/shinybulma/pull/29) on `shinybulma` so this should be fixed.